# How to ping IP address and check connectivity from Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a Forms 6i application. It retrieves data from a remote location and if there is no network connectivity, an error is generated and users cannot work.

I need to ping the remote location and check if the connection is available and if it is not available, take data from a local table and display on the form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HOST` built-in. It lets you execute an operating system command (which PING is).

Comment: but how to check the response and act accordingly?

Comment: Redirect its output to a file and check what's in there. Alternatively, you could write a function which utilizes UTL_TCP package & try to talk to that site; then handle what it returns. Here's an example on OraFAQ Forum, have a look: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/63207/440008/#msg_440008